# What does "_(items)" do when calling a JS function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Javascript newbie here.  While I'm learning Higher order functions in JavaScript, I see the following example.  Could someone explain what _(item) do before calling .chain()?  Thank you.

```
//items is an array with nested objects as elements
var count = _(items).chain()
      .flatten()
      .reduce(.....)
      .value();
```

Comment: Have you [looked at the Underscore documentation at all](http://underscorejs.org/#chain)?

Comment: Actually, in your defense, the Underscore docs do a terrible job of explaining what the `_` function itself does.

Comment: I did before posting here.  All I found was _(...) in the doc, but no clear explanation.  If you are the down-voter, I suggest you to be more helpful than talking in a condescending way.

Comment: I upvoted this to remove downvote. A little tip that has served me well. Don't be afraid to look at the source code. Open up the library and do a search for _() function and read it. You don't just get to see how it works but also you see good function composition etc. Often you learn more than docs could ever tech you.. There's a good saying in the us community...'it's just JS' it's not magic!

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. Basically the `_` function "wraps" the object, which makes it possible to do those chained calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_(items).chain()` is equivalent to `_.chain(items)`. Both are used to make [object-oriented style syntax](http://underscorejs.org/#oop) possible, where  methods are chained that act on the previous result. The first value you start with must thus somehow be *wrapped* so it understands such underscore methods.

The `_(items)` call on its own (without `.chain()`) will provide you underscore's methods, but the result cannot be chained further. The `_.chain(items)` call not only provide access to the underscore methods, but also makes sure that this behaviour continues, allowing underscore methods to be chained further.

The change log can be helpful to understand why there are these two syntaxes:

> **0.4.0** — *November 7, 2009* — Diff — Docs
>
> All Underscore functions can now be called in an object-oriented style, like so: `_([1, 2, 3]).map(...);`.
>
> **1.2.4** — *January 4, 2012* — Diff — Docs
>
> You now can (and probably should, as it's simpler) write `_.chain(list)` instead of `_(list).chain()`.

So the syntax you quoted is the "older" syntax.